# How would I make this pascal triangle into a square?

Tags: java

How would I make this pascal triangle into a square?

```
import java.util.*;     
public class PascalSquare { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int row = 7;
    int[][] pascal  = new int[row +1][];
    pascal[1] = new int[1 + 2];
    pascal[1][1] = 1;


    for (int i = 2; i <= row; i++) {
        pascal[i] = new int[i + 2];
        for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++) {
            pascal[i][j] = pascal[i-1][j-1] + pascal[i-1][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(pascal[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

// I want this to be a 7*7 square that will follow the same principle as a pascal triangle(adding the numbers above)

Comment: So what troubles are you facing?

Comment: Well, I can't figure out how to modify the code so that it performs the same task as a pascal triangle but in the form of a square.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're trying to get?

Comment: if it were to be a 3*3, I want to get

Comment: 111 (new line) 123 (newline) 136

Comment: I can see what you want but it cannot be called a Pascal triangle and not only because you want a square, In PT you always make a sum of two numbers, you want from left to right to have a sum of 1,2,3,4... numbers. Still, a very basic loop you should be able to solve by yourself.